# \titlespacing* with a negative before-sep makes PDF bookmark aim too low

Tags: hyperref, titlesec, bookmarks

When I use `\titlespacing*` with a negative *before-sep* to make the chapter title higher, clicking the title in the PDF bookmark will navigate to a lower position. With the following MWE, the title will be entirely missing from the viewport.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\Huge\filcenter}
{\thechapter}
{0.5em}{}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{20pt}   % PDF bookmark misses the title
% \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{20pt}  % this one feels correct

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

On my machine, both pdflatex and xelatex give the same result (with titlesec v2.10.0 and hyperref v6.83m). How to fix this issue, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a timing problem. Rather than using `-50pt` in `\titlespacing`, remove the vertical space from `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{50}{0}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{50}{0}{}{}
\makeatother

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
  {\Huge\filcenter}
  {\thechapter}
  {0.5em}
  {}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}                                  

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\lipsum[1-16]
\section{A}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]